# How to add 3D features in Online ArcGIS (Story Map)

Tags: arcgis-online, 3d, arcscene, 3d-model, 3d-map

How to add 3D features in Online ArcGIS (Story Map) - I created the 3D layers / features using ArcMap Desktop and ArcScene

I'm a student and a newbie looking for detailed information.

Comment: What has your research found so far?  Searching on "3d ArcGIS online" would be my starting point.

Comment: Arc isn't so good at 3d features... normally I'd take 2d features and fit them to a surface with a tool like Interpolate Shape (3d analyst license) http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00q90000006m000000.. or if capturing look at Default Z in editor http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISDesktop/dotnet/be988544-4964-4b55-9586-b7d499c6ed10.htm if you want to modify the Z value of individual vertices right click and select 'Edit Vertices' and an editable table will appear with each points coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

A quick search uncovered [Make your first scene](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/make-your-first-scene.htm) in the ArcGIS Online Help:

> A scene is symbolized 3D geospatial content that includes a multiscale
>   basemap, a collection of 2D and 3D layers, styles, and configurations
>   that allow you to visualize and analyze geographic information in an
>   intuitive and interactive 3D environment.You can create scenes with
>   the built-in scene viewer or with ArcGIS Pro. To create scenes, you
>   need to be signed in with an organizational account or a public
>   account.

and blog postings called:

- [Using 3D web scenes in Story Maps](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/03/20/using-web-scenes-in-story-maps/)
- [Using 3D web scenes in Story Maps redux](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/07/17/using-3d-web-scenes-in-story-maps-redux/)

These seem to be geared around ArcGIS Pro rather than ArcMap/ArcScene as your authoring tools but I think you should be able to open the items that you have authored in ArcMap and ArcScene in ArcGIS Pro.